# Scale-free network using preferential attachment algorithm

Tags: python, networkx

I'm having trouble understanding what this piece of code does. Please could someone step by step go through the code and explain how it works and what it's doing?

```
def scale_free(n,m):
    if m < 1 or  m >=n: 
        raise nx.NetworkXError("Preferential attactment algorithm must have m >= 1"
                               " and m < n, m = %d, n = %d" % (m, n)) 
    # Add m initial nodes (m0 in barabasi-speak)
    G=nx.empty_graph(m)

    # Target nodes for new edges
    targets=list(range(m))
    # List of existing nodes, with nodes repeated once for each adjacent edge
    repeated_nodes=[]
    # Start adding the other n-m nodes. The first node is m.
    source=m
    while source<n:
        # Add edges to m nodes from the source.
        G.add_edges_from(zip([source]*m,targets))
        # Add one node to the list for each new edge just created.
        repeated_nodes.extend(targets)
        # And the new node "source" has m edges to add to the list.
        repeated_nodes.extend([source]*m)
        # Now choose m unique nodes from the existing nodes
        # Pick uniformly from repeated_nodes (preferential attachement)
        targets = _random_subset(repeated_nodes,m)
        source += 1
    return G
```

Comment: Hi @killerownage2006, the code is very well documented in the comments.  Is there something specific you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first part of this makes sure that `m` is at least 1 and `n>m`.

```
def scale_free(n,m):
    if m < 1 or  m >=n: 
        raise nx.NetworkXError("Preferential attactment algorithm must have m >= 1"
                               " and m < n, m = %d, n = %d" % (m, n))
```

Then it creates a graph with no edges and the first `m` nodes `0`, `1`, ..., `m-1`.
This looks a bit different from the standard barabasi-albert graph which starts from a connected version, rather than a version without any edges.

```
    # Add m initial nodes (m0 in barabasi-speak)
    G=nx.empty_graph(m)
```

Now it's going to start adding new nodes 1 at a time and connecting them to existing nodes based on various rules.  It first creates a set of "targets" that has all of the nodes in the edge-less graph.

```
    # Target nodes for new edges
    targets=list(range(m))
    # List of existing nodes, with nodes repeated once for each adjacent edge
    repeated_nodes=[]
    # Start adding the other n-m nodes. The first node is m.
    source=m
```

Now it's going to add each node 1 at a time.  When it does that, it will add the new node with edges to `m` of the previous existing nodes.  Those `m` previous nodes have been stored in a list called `targets`.

```
    while source<n:
```

Here it creates those edges

```
        # Add edges to m nodes from the source.
        G.add_edges_from(zip([source]*m,targets))
```

Now it's going to decide who will get those edges when the next node is added.  It's supposed to choose them with probability proportional to their degree  The way it does that is by having a list `repeated_nodes` which has each node appearing once per edge.  It then chooses a random set of `m` nodes from that to be the new targets.  Depending on how `_random_subset` is defined, it might or might not be able to choose the same node several times to be a target in the same step.

```
        # Add one node to the list for each new edge just created.
        repeated_nodes.extend(targets)
        # And the new node "source" has m edges to add to the list.
        repeated_nodes.extend([source]*m)
        # Now choose m unique nodes from the existing nodes
        # Pick uniformly from repeated_nodes (preferential attachement)
        targets = _random_subset(repeated_nodes,m)
        source += 1
    return G
```

Comment: Thank you alot! That helped with my understanding :)